# Firestore Security Rules for Validating that Only a Single Array Map Is Being Changed

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My app has a user collection, and each authenticated user has a document in this collection.

### Goal

My security rules should allow an authenticated user to update their own document (where auth.uid matches document ID), and allow any authenticated user to update *one field* in any other user's document.

This field, 'memberships', is an array, where each item in the array is a map of two fields: 'groupId', and 'status':

[image]

### Problem

My issue is with updating another user's document, but just the single field. Multiple other questions suggest how I can do this, but those don't see to work.

In this example, the item in question is a list of mapped values with multiple keys, and I'm wondering if that's what makes this one not work.

## Update May 12th - clean up existing code

Current Security Rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        // Allow users to read their own user document
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    
    // Allow authorized user to edit their own user document
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    // Allow any user to update the 'memberships' field in any user document
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow update: if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly('memberships');
    }
  }
  }
```

And here is the function where I'm running into the issue - you can skip down to the section where I try to complete a batch.

```
  Future<FailureOrSuccess> _confirmUpdateValidityAndUpdate(
      User user, Group group) async {

    MemberOfGroup memberInUser = MemberOfGroup.invited(groupId: group.id);

    ValueResult<User> userResult =
        user.addOrUpdateMembership(memberInUser);

    if (userResult.isFailure) {
      return const GroupFailure.invalidMembershipUpdate();
    }

    User userForUpdate = userResult.value;

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> userMemberships = [
      for (var membership in userForUpdate.memberships)
        MemberOfGroupDto.fromDomain(membership).toJson()
    ];
    
    try {
      print(user.id);
      // I've tried both 'set' and 'update' - both still have this issue.
      await _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.id)
          .set({'memberships': userMemberships});
      return const Success();
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return mapFirebaseExceptionToFailure(e);
    }
  }
```

Also, don't know if this would matter, but the UserMembership field is a List<Map<String, dynamic>> - not sure if that would matter:

```
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> userMemberships = [
      for (var membership in userForUpdate.memberships)
        MemberOfGroupDto.fromDomain(membership).toJson()
    ];
```

Here is the error I'm seeing:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This does not do what you want:

```
request.resource.data.keys().size() == 1
```

The `request.resource` contains the document as it will exist after the operation succeeded, so it contains all fields of your document. If you want to only allow the user to modify certain fields, you'll want to have a look at the `affectedKeys` of a [map diff](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020). From there:

```
// This rule only allows updates where "a" is the only field affected
allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["a"]);
```

So you could use this to ensure that only the `memberships` is affected by the user.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I did try that one - noted in the question above, and that doesn't seem to work. I added a screenshot. Based on how this is setup, would just specifying the 'memberships' key be sufficient? Or would I need to also specify the groupId/status keys?

Comment: Ah, I only checked the first code snippet - which only checks the length. What isn't working about the second rules? Can you edit your question to show the one set of rules you actually test with, and the minimal code you can reproduce the problem with?

Comment: Hey Frank - I added my current security rules and a code snippet of the function where I'm hitting the issue. I have it set up as you've suggested and it still says I don't have permissions. It is part of a batch that's also updating another collection, but I think the issue is with the update to the user collection (the groups collection has very broad rules right now).

Comment: The problem should not be in the other write indeed, but (given that we're looking for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) you can ensure that is the case by removing the other write altogether and checking if it them works. Same with using a batched write: can you get the same problem we a regular `_firestore.userCollection.doc(user.id).update(...)` call? If so, that's simpler to reason about than a batch update - so prefered.

Comment: Finally: are you certain the document already exists? You're not checking that in your code, but you are calling `update` (which fails when the document doesn't exist) and your rules only allow updates.

Comment: Hey Frank. Thanks for the tips. I removed the other write/batch, so it's just a single write call. I tried with both "set" and "update" and I updated my security rules to allow 'update, write' instead of just update. I am still getting the error (I've pasted a screenshot at the bottom of the question).

Comment: Simplify, simplify, simplify please! If the new code is simpler and reproduces the problem, you can remove the original code. --- Next step, how do you know that `user.id` matches the `if request.auth.uid == userId` condition? Specifically: are you certain it's the UID of the current user (so `request.auth.uid`)? I don't know what `User user` is, but consider using the value directly from Firebase Authentication instead: `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid`.

Comment: I simplified the code and cleaned up. In this case though, `user.id` doesn't match the `request.auth.uid == userId` condition. I am expecting it to return false for that condition, but then match the last condition, where `if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly('memberships');`

Comment: Good point, I forgot that if there are multiple `match` condition for an operation it is allowed if *any* of them allows the operation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements --- Still, your code should then probably check if `request.auth != null` is being met too: `if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null)`